# Why do I get 'Item is required' when updating an item in DynamoDB using AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to push a DynamoDB record through Step Functions while setting up a conditional expression but for some reason, I'm getting the error:

> There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
> The field 'Item' is required but was missing (at /States/MyStep/Parameters)

I don't want to push an `Item`. I want to use an update expression.

Here's my code:

```json
{
  "StartAt": "MyStep",
  "States": {
    "MyStep": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName.$": "$.table_name",
        "Key": {
          "test_id_path_method_executor_id": {"S.$": "$.update_key.test_id_path_method_executor_id"},
          "result_timestamp": {"S.$": "$.update_key.result_timestamp"}
        },
        "ConditionExpression": "#max_db < :max_values",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
          ":max_values": {"N.$": "$.result_value"}
        },
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
          "#max_db": "max"
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "SET #max_db = :max_values"
      },
      "Next": "EndSuccess"
    },
    "EndSuccess": {
      "Type":"Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main DynamoDB APIs for modifying items:

1. [`PutItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)
2. [`UpdateItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)

In a nutshell, `PutItem` 'updates' the item by replacing it & because of this, it requires the replacement item to be passed. This is the API call you're using and is why you're getting `The field 'Item' is required but was missing`. It's correct, `Item` *is* required when using `PutItem`.

Instead, you need to use `UpdateItem` which does not require the new item in full & will modify the attributes of an item based on an update expression (which is what you have).

In your step function definition, replace:

```json
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
```

With:

```json
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:updateItem",
```